# Can I stop notifications of Steam groups I have joined?

Tags: steam

I'm a member of many groups because of the freebies I get from Gleam. I don't want any notifications or their feeds in my friend's activity while being the part of group.

Comment: [In 2017 Steam added a setting to disable group notifications](https://store.steampowered.com/news/28060/), but I don't know if the setting exists anymore. In [the 2018 chat update](https://steamcommunity.com/updates/chatupdate) the ["friends" tab](https://youtu.be/1zJOgD4NYWw?t=19) was removed from Steam settings.

Comment: Technically you're asking two questions, since you both want to disable notifications and group events in your activity feed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So i dont know if the solution i can give you also results in the Steam Client not giving you notifications from groups anymore.

I did this in the Browser:

Navigate to your Player Tab and click on activity:
[image]

If you are on your activity page on the top of the list there is a link called Friend Activity Settings:

[image]

Now you should see a lot of options and checkboxes. Scroll down until you find the groupbox **A Group i belong to**:

[image]

You can change the settings now and save it on the bottom of the page.

As i said above i dont know if this is just for the activity feed or also for the steam client (which theoretically would be logic).

Comment: Replace username in this URL: https://steamcommunity.com/id/username/blotteredit